# How to convert Array into JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

A quick simple question, if i have

```
var obj = [ [contacts : [ name : "name1" , number : "number1" ] ], 
[contacts : [ name: "name2" , number : "number2" ] ]  ... ];
```

i want to convert it to a single Json string.

How to do this ?

Comment: your "Json object" is invalid.

Comment: JSON is a string format used to represent an object, not an "object" in itself.

Comment: Do you mean JSON string?

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't. An array is the correct data type to store what you have.

Comment: @KevinB (in response to your comment on all the downvotes): `JSON.stringify()` outputs a string which is not what the OP wants. The OP wants a "real" data structure.

Comment: How can we possibly tell that from his question? what he listed as his "goal" isn't possible.

Comment: A valid format would be: var obj = [ {name: "name1", number: "number1"}, {name: "name2", number: "number2"} ];

Comment: @HJ05 Tell me why wrapping up in [ {contacts: {name: ... } } ] is invalid?

Comment: Wrapping in `[]` IS valid, wrapping in `{}` is not unless you also provide a key.

Comment: @KevinB sorry, i meant a json string, edited the question.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: sorry, but your example still isn't a string

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It doesnt actually "my" choice here, i need to return data in a specific format as a response from server. It needs to be like this.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta what you are doing here has nothing to do with changing the format that the server returns... And your second sample is invalid in any way you look at it. it isn't json, and it isn't javascript. At most it could be a **useless** string, if you wrapped it in single quotes and escaped the newline characters.

Comment: I didn't mean what you have is invalid, it's just that what I show is simpler and more concise and a better use of the format. You have the property contacts, but it only contains one object. Using what you have your access code would be obj[0].contacts.name and someone reading that would assume contacts should be an array since it is plural. With what I show you would just have obj[0].name and the reader would just assume that obj is an array of contacts. It's just a matter of using a better naming convention.

Comment: Is this an X/Y situation? he needs to do X, and tried Y, but Y isn't working and wants to fix Y, when we really should be fixing X? He's getting json from the server that gets converted to an array, he needs the array to be in a different format to work with some arbitrary plugin, so he's trying to... make a differently formatted json string instead of changing the format of the object/array.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the following to get a better idea why the second is invalid JSON: http://www.json.org/

Comment: If you really want to create such a string, try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mm74s/). It calls `JSON.stringify()` and replaced the square brackets at both ends by curly braces. However, I strongly recommend reading my post. The result will be *invalid*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Why your proposed result is invalid

Your proposed result is invalid. It can never exist.

Objects (as indicated by curly braces `{...}`) are essentially dictionaries. They map keys to values. It is therefore invalid to not specify any keys (as you did).

The data structure you are seeking for are **arrays**, which are indicated by square brackets (`[...]`).

You can of course mimic array-like behavior by specifying numbered indices in your dictionary:

```
var obj = {
  0: firstElement,
  1: secondElement
};

// the same as*
var arr = [firstElement, secondElement];
```

*) Note that `obj` and `arr` are not equivalent! While arrays are objects, objects at their raw form do not provide array functions, e.g. `obj.length` will be undefined.

#### JSON != Object literal notation

You seem to confuse the term **JSON** with the syntax you are using in your *JavaScript* code, which is called **Object literal notation**

**JSON**
It is a data format.

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
// or
[
  "first",
  "second"
]
...
```

Double quotes around keys are required. Consult http://json.org for more information on the syntax.

**Object Literals**
Those are embedded in JavaScript code.

```
// JS code
alert("Test, this is JS code"); // sample

var obj = {
  1: "abc",
  2: ["first", "second"]
};
```

Double quotes around keys are optional in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

Comment: why are answers suggesting to stringify his var being so downvoted? am i missing the question? this is exactly what he's asking for, even if he doesn't understand the result that would come from it..

Comment: @KevinB Clearly we disagree on what's being asked. As far as I'm concerned he wants to do exactly what he's asking: convert an array into an object. He doesn't want to create a string that still represents the array.

Comment: we should get clarification from the author and correct the question, or close it.

Comment: @KevinB I suspect because it's not clear what he's asking for. To some, he seems to be asking for an object. Whether or not that's actually what he wants is anyone's guess.

Comment: Now he seems to be asking for a json string.

Comment: @KevinB He's asking for a JSON string in a format that isn't what he'd get from stringifying his array, so I'm not convinced he actually understands the concepts involved.

Comment: That's obvious, but whether or not he understands it, the answer to converting an object or array to a json string is to... stringify it.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah I agree. I don't think the downvotes for this answer are called for because 1) the question wasn't clear and 2) the OP probably meant string because that's really the only option.

Comment: @sentil: It seems you gave the correct answer after all! +1!

Comment: @linstantnoodles To be honest, I usually want to downvote answers that are just "Try this: " followed by code anyway, because I don't think they're really all that useful. If they also fail to answer what's been asked for - even if it's impossible - then I'm definitely going to do so. That said, since the question has been clarified (to a point), I've reversed my downvote; if they do in fact want to generate a string then this is the correct method.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist fair enough. I agree - "try this" answers are usually not very helpful. In cases like this where the question is ambiguous, they don't even show an attempt to understand the problem. It's just like "ok here hope this works kthxbye". I feel like I've been guilty of this at some point haha.

Comment: if it is indeed just asking to stringify an array, it's a duplicate that should be closed. but i think this question is more than that after the op clarified with comments.